# Distributed Availability Group between a domain and a workgroup

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I want to implement “Distributed Availability Group” on Windows Server 2016 and SQL Server 2019 and between a domain and a workgroup.

I follow the steps that described in this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-distributed-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=automatic

My architecture is: (I should mention all IP address are fake)

### (Data Center 1)

WSFC: on windows server 2016, name is: Test1_CLS

Availability Group: AG1

Domain Name: test.com

Primary Replica: (IP Address = 1.1.1.1, computer name = node_1, Full Computer Name = node_1.test.com)

Secondary Replica: (IP Address = 1.1.1.2, computer name = node_2, Full Computer Name = node_2.test.com)

### (Data Center 2)

WSFC: on windows server 2016, name is: Test2_CLS

Availability Group: AG2

Workgroup

Primary Replica: (IP Address = 1.1.1.3, computer name = node_3, Full Computer Name = node_3.test.com)

I want to create a distributed availability group between AG1 & AG2. Since we have the combination of a domain and a workgroup, I implemented a domain-independent availability group. For this purpose, I did below steps:

1.I defined a DNS suffix with the value “test.com” in node_3 so the full computer name of this node is: “node_3.test.com”

2.I added the server FQDN & related IP address into C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts.file on each node.
When a failover process happen, the role of servers will be changed so I added all FQDN’s into each node’s host file & be able to access each other.

In each node_1, node_2 & node_3 host files:

1.1.1.1 node_1.test.com

1.1.1.2 node_2.test.com

1.1.1.3 node_3.test.com

3.I created a local user on each node with the name “Clusteradmin” with the same password and Put this user into administrators group.

4.I changed the SQL Server Service account to “Clusteradmin” in each node.

5.In each of nodes I run below statement in windows PowerShell:

New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -Name LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy -Value 1

6.In “node_1” that has a primary role, I logged in with “Clusteradmin” user then I created a WSFC that include these nodes: “node_1”, ‘node_2’.

7.Since SQL Server Service account on each nodes runs with non-domain user account so, I defined certificates in order to correct accessing to endpoints.

I did:

-On node_1 (Primary Replica):

use master

create master key encryption by password = 'P@ssw0rd';

create certificate node_1_Certificate_Private with subject = 'Crtificate
node_1'

Backup Certificate node_1_Certificate_Private to file =
'E:\node_1_Certificate_Private.cert'

CREATE ENDPOINT [endpoint]

STATE = STARTED

AS TCP (

```
      LISTENER_PORT = 5022, LISTENER_IP = ALL
```

)

FOR DATA_MIRRORING

(
ROLE = ALL,

```
    AUTHENTICATION = Certificate node_1_Certificate_Private,

    ENCRYPTION = REQUIRED ALGORITHM AES

    )
```

-On node_2 (Secondary Replica):

use master

create master key encryption by password = 'P@ssw0rd';

create certificate node_2_Certificate_Private with subject = 'Crtificate node_2'

Backup Certificate node_2_Certificate_Private to file = 'E:\node_2_Certificate_Private.cert'

CREATE ENDPOINT [endpoint]

STATE = STARTED

AS TCP (
LISTENER_PORT = 5022, LISTENER_IP = ALL
)

FOR DATA_MIRRORING

```
   (
```

ROLE = ALL,

```
    AUTHENTICATION = Certificate node_2_Certificate_Private,

    ENCRYPTION = REQUIRED ALGORITHM AES

    )
```

-On node_3 (Primary Replica):

use master

create master key encryption by password = 'P@ssw0rd';

create certificate node_3_Certificate_Private with subject = 'Crtificate node_3'

Backup Certificate node_3_Certificate_Private to file = 'E:\node_3_Certificate_Private.cert'

CREATE ENDPOINT [endpoint]

STATE = STARTED

AS TCP (

```
      LISTENER_PORT = 5022, LISTENER_IP = ALL

    )
```

FOR DATA_MIRRORING

```
   (    ROLE = ALL, 

    AUTHENTICATION = Certificate node_3_Certificate_Private,

    ENCRYPTION = REQUIRED ALGORITHM AES

    )
```

-Copy created certificates into each node.

-On node_1 (Primary Replica):

use master

create login node_2_Login with password = 'P@ssw0rd'

create user node_2_User for login node_2_Login

create login node_3_Login with password = 'P@ssw0rd'

create user node_3_User for login node_3_Login

Create Certificate node_1_Public_Cert_1
Authorization node_2_User From File = 'E:\node_2_Certificate_Private.cert'

Create Certificate node_1_Public_Cert_2
Authorization node_3_User From File = 'E:\node_3_Certificate_Private.cert'

Grant Connect ON Endpoint :: [endpoint] To node_2_Login

Grant Connect ON Endpoint :: [endpoint] To node_3_Login

-On node_2 (Secondary Replica):

use master

create login node_1_Login with password = 'P@ssw0rd'

create user node_1_User for login node_1_Login

create login node_3_Login with password = 'P@ssw0rd'

create user node_3_User for login node_3_Login

Create Certificate node_2_Public_Cert_1
Authorization node_1_User From File = 'E:\node_1_Certificate_Private.cert'

Create Certificate node_2_Public_Cert_2
Authorization node_3_User From File = 'E:\node_3_Certificate_Private.cert'

Grant Connect ON Endpoint :: [endpoint] To node_1_Login

Grant Connect ON Endpoint :: [endpoint] To node_3_Login

-On node_3 (Primary Replica):

use master

create login node_1_Login with password = 'P@ssw0rd'

create user node_1_User for login node_1_Login

use master

create login node_2_Login with password = 'P@ssw0rd'

create user node_2_User for login node_2_Login

Create Certificate node_3_Public_Cert_1
Authorization node_1_User From File = 'E:\node_1_Certificate_Private.cert'

Create Certificate node_3_Public_Cert_2
Authorization node_2_User From File = 'E:\node_2_Certificate_Private.cert'

Grant Connect ON Endpoint :: [endpoint] To node_1_Login

Grant Connect ON Endpoint :: [endpoint] To node_2_Login

8.Create the first availability group on global primary replica (node_1), run below statement:

USE [master]

CREATE AVAILABILITY GROUP [AG1]

FOR DATABASE [db_Test]

REPLICA ON

N'node_1'

WITH (
ENDPOINT_URL = N'TCP://node_1.test.com:5022',

```
    FAILOVER_MODE = AUTOMATIC, 

    AVAILABILITY_MODE = SYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT, 

    BACKUP_PRIORITY = 50, 

    SECONDARY_ROLE(ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = ALL),

    SEEDING_MODE = AUTOMATIC    
),
```

N'node_2'

WITH (
ENDPOINT_URL = N'TCP://node_2.test.com:5022',

```
    FAILOVER_MODE = AUTOMATIC, 

    AVAILABILITY_MODE = SYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT, 

    BACKUP_PRIORITY = 50, 

    SECONDARY_ROLE(ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = ALL),

    SEEDING_MODE = AUTOMATIC    
);
```

9. On Secondary replica (node_2) in first availability group, run below statement:

ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [AG1] JOIN

ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [AG1] GRANT CREATE ANY DATABASE

10. On global primary replica (node_1) in first availability group, create a listener:

USE [master]

ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [AG1]
ADD LISTENER N'Test1_LTS' (WITH IP ((N'1.1.1.10', N'0.0.0.0')), PORT = 81);

11. Create the second availability group on forwarder replica (node_3), run below statement:

USE [master]

CREATE AVAILABILITY GROUP [AG2]

FOR

REPLICA ON

N'node_3'

WITH (
ENDPOINT_URL = N'TCP://node_3.test.com:5022',

```
    FAILOVER_MODE = MANUAL, 

    AVAILABILITY_MODE = SYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT, 

    BACKUP_PRIORITY = 50, 

    PRIMARY_ROLE(ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = ALL), 

    SECONDARY_ROLE(ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = ALL),

    SEEDING_MODE = AUTOMATIC    
);
```

12. On forwarder replica (node_3) in Second availability group, create a listener:

USE [master]

ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [AG2]
ADD LISTENER N'Test2_LTS' (WITH IP ((N'1.1.1.11', N'0.0.0.0')), PORT = 82);

Now we create a distributed availability group:

13.On global primary replica (node_1) in first availability group, create a distributed availability group:

CREATE AVAILABILITY GROUP [DAG_Test_2]

WITH (DISTRIBUTED)

AVAILABILITY GROUP ON

```
  'AG1' WITH    

  (   

     LISTENER_URL = 'tcp://Test1_LTS:5022',    

     AVAILABILITY_MODE = ASYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT,   

     FAILOVER_MODE = MANUAL,   

     SEEDING_MODE = AUTOMATIC   

  ),   

  'AG2' WITH    

  (   

     LISTENER_URL = 'tcp://Test2_LTS:5022',   

     AVAILABILITY_MODE = ASYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT,   

     FAILOVER_MODE = MANUAL,   

     SEEDING_MODE = AUTOMATIC   
  );
```

14. On forwarder replica (node_3) in Second availability group, join second availability group to DAG_Test_2:

ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [DAG_Test_2]

JOIN

AVAILABILITY GROUP ON

```
'AG1' WITH    

(   

    LISTENER_URL = 'tcp://Test1_LTS:5022',     

    AVAILABILITY_MODE = ASYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT,   

    FAILOVER_MODE = MANUAL,   

    SEEDING_MODE = AUTOMATIC   

),   

'AG2' WITH    

(   

    LISTENER_URL = 'tcp://Test2_LTS:5022', 

    AVAILABILITY_MODE = ASYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT,   

    FAILOVER_MODE = MANUAL,   

    SEEDING_MODE = AUTOMATIC   

);
```

After running statement above, SQL Server prompts “Command Completed Successfully” but AG2 does not join to DAG_Test_2 and “db_Test” database is not restored into “node_3”.

Since the AG2 did not join to DAG_Test_2 so I could not run below statement:

ALTER DATABASE [db_Test] SET HADR AVAILABILITY GROUP = [AG2];

I searched a lot but I find no answer for this problem.

Could you please check my code and give me some advise?

I should mention I want to implement DAG between domain and workgroup OR different domains.

Are the things I did before creating availability groups right for this purpose?

Comment: Have you validated each of your AGs before trying create the distributed AG?

Comment: Yes, They were validated.

Comment: I'd start by looking at the errorlog.